# Opposing homonyms

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, homonyms, homographs

I'm aware of precisely one word that is spelled and pronounced the same, yet has a completely opposite meaning depending on its context: **sanction**.

On one hand, it is official permission for something.

On the other hand, it is a penalty (so, the opposite of permission).

Yet you could sanction (give permission for) a sanction (penalty to be applied). Hm.

Are there any other homonyms that share this trait of having directly opposing meanings?

Comment: Yes, at least a few. Look around and tell us what you found! Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These words are called auto-antonyms or contronyms; [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) has an extensive list of examples in the English language, including your 'sanction'.

My favourite is 'oversight':

> **"Oversight"** can mean "accidental omission or error", or "close scrutiny and control".

since they (too) often occur together...

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - wasn't aware of the precise term for this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no homonyms, synonyms, homographs, none.

It's a **Janus word**, a type of polysemy, more precisely, "[auto-antonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) (WP)."

> An **auto-antonym** or **autantonym**, also called a **contronym** or **contranym**,[2] is a word with multiple meanings (senses) of which one is the reverse of another. For example, the word *cleave* can mean "to cut apart" or "to bind together". This phenomenon is called **enantiosemy**,[3][4] **enantionymy** or **antilogy** (enantio- means "opposite"). An enantiosemic term is necessarily polysemic.
> …
> **antagonym, enantiodrome, self-antonym, antilogy**, or **addad** (Arabic, singular **didd**).
> …
> "**Draw**" the curtains can mean either to open them or to close them.
> "**Dust**" can mean to remove dust (cleaning a house) or to add dust (e.g. to dust a cake with powdered sugar).